# MySQL JDBC closeOnCompletion has no effect on PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

JDBC introduced a method called *closeOnAutoCompletion*, which states that it closes the statement, when all dependent resultSets are close.

I have a method to create prepared statements

```
public final PreparedStatement statement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
            ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    stmt.closeOnCompletion();
    return stmt;
}
```

No I'm calling this method as follows

```
@Test
public void testCloseOnCompletionSemiManually() throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement stmt = shards.statement(db);
    assertTrue("Statement must be closeOnAutoCompletion", stmt.isCloseOnCompletion());

    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            //System.out.println("Shard id: " + rs.getInt("SHARD_ID"));
        }
    }
    assertTrue("Statement must be closed after all results sets have been processed", stmt.isClosed());
}
```

The last check fails as the statement is not closed.

Is this a problem due to the mysql implementation? Or did I missunderstand the JavaDoc.

**Update**: I'm using version 5.1.24

thanks,
Muki

Comment: Maybe the close is asynchronous? Try sleeping for some time after exiting try clause. If it does not help you found yourself a bug :)

Comment: It is entirely possible to the MySQL driver hasn't implemented this yet.

Comment: It's true the implementation is very new. However I want to check if I'm doing something wrong, before opening a bug

Comment: I openend a bug http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68916  The implementation looks more like a placeholder (StatementImpl Line 3041)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The driver doesn't support it yet, however the test is not correct either. Note that the API docs for Statement say that closeOnCompletion() closes the statement when all dependent result sets are **closed**, not scrolled past the end, so I'm not sure what behavior is actually assumed to be happening in your case.

Comment: It uses try-with-resources. Java will automatically call the `ResultSet.close()` method at the end of the try block.

Comment: BTW: How do you know it doesn't support it, the [5.1.21 release announcement](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,559877,559877) seems to indicate it is supported

Comment: I looked at the implementation (5.1.24) and the implementation seems more like a placeholder. A flag plus the API methods. My IDE wasn't able to find any usages of the methods/flags internally in the mysql driver.

Regarding the test. The resultSet is closed. I also checked if there are other open resultSets. Nope. So this should work, as it is the simplest use case.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this announcement](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,559877,559877), version 5.1.21 of the MySQL Connector/J (the official name of the JDBC driver for MySQL) should support *closeOnAutoCompletion*. Can you check you're using that version?

Comment: He is using new feature of java 7 - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: The `ResultSet` is being closed by the try-with-resources block; if `closeOnCompletion` is correctly implemented, this should result in a close of the `Statement` as well.